# OData: Generate the $metadata document from a IEdmModel

Tags: odata

I can generate an `IEdmModel` from a $metadata document with something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://services.odata.org/v3/odata/OData.svc/$metadata");
ClientHttpResponseMessage metadataMessage = new ClientHttpResponseMessage((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());
using (var messageReader = new ODataMessageReader(metadataMessage))
{
    IEdmModel model = messageReader.ReadMetadataDocument();
}
```

Is there a way to do the reverse? Given a `IEdmModel` generate the metadata document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use odl writer to write the metadata from IEdmModel. 
Class ODataMessageWriter have function WriteMetadataDocument. Assuming you have IEdmModel model, you can use following code to write metadata to message.

```
using (var msgWriter = new ODataMessageWriter((IODataResponseMessage)message, writerSettings, model))
{
  msgWriter.WriteMetadataDocument();
}
```