# Get OData metadata in camel case

Tags: odata

I know using EnableLowerCamelCase, we can responses in camel case. But using this property, we don't get metadata in camelCase.

Is there a way to get metadata also in camel case?

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData from NuGet Package
2. StartUp.cs

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }
     else
     {
       app.UseHsts();
     }
     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
     {
       routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection(); //This Is added for OData
       //Added this 2 line in your Code
       var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
       builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655156/odata-generate-the-metadata-document-from-a-iedmmodel    Please refer link its help for you.